# Break event_base_dispatch from another thread

Tags: c++, libevent

Can I call `event_base_loopbreak` to `int event_base_dispatch(struct event_base *base)` that run in another thread?

Comment: Adding about 2~3 lines of context makes it quite a bit more probable that people can answer your question - this is **really** concise.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to stop `event_base_dispatch` with `event_base_loopbreak` from another thread. Just enable multithreading support by calling `evthread_use_pthreads` or `evthread_use_windows_threads` before `event_base` created.

Comment: I had this problem where event_base_loop used with EVLOOP_NO_EXIT_ON_EMPTY in another thread, is not executing events created in main thread. Once I put the evthread_use_pthreads before event_base creation phew.. it worked. Very thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Calling event_base_loopbreak from outside of the event loop doesn't actually have an effect and inside the loop, event_base_loopbreak does not break from the loop. So, calling event_base_loopbreak to int event_base_dispatch(struct event_base *base) that run in another thread, should not have any effect.

Comment: So, how can I stop event_base_dispatch from another thread? OR can I add event to event_base while event_base_dispatch is working?

Answer (score 1):

I'm also meet the same issue, no matter calling event_base_loopbreak() or event_add() from other thread are not working.

Ref to [How to break out libevent's dispatch loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219314/how-to-break-out-libevents-dispatch-loop), I had to set a timer event before start the event loop, and polling the exit flag to call event_base_loopbreak() from the event's callback, that can exit the event loop successfully